# Do open continuous maps/local homeomorphisms between locales possess adjoints?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors, monomorphisms, locales

Recently I started learning "theory of locales" (point-free topology) by my-self. While being a very beautiful, natural subject and parallel to point-set topology, some of its notions are bit hard to understand due to the way map between locales has defined and (imho) heavy use of category theory.

- An open continuous map $f : X\to Y$ between locales means that the corresponding formal dual frame homomorphism $f^*: \operatorname{Open}(Y)\to \operatorname{Open}(X)$ has a left adjoint $f_!: \operatorname{Open}(X)\to \operatorname{Open}(Y)$
  satisfying the Frobenius reciprocity condition: $f_!(a\land f^*(b))=f_!(a)\land b.$
- Further, if $f$ is a local homeomorphism, then $f^*$ has a right adjoint $f_*.$ Also, $f_!$ is equal to $f_*$ (correct me if I am wrong in this second point).

Here is my question:

> Does this means that open $f$ has a right adjoint (as a map of locales)?
> And, locale homeomorphisms have both adjoints?

I am interested in this question because of the following sub-questions: Suppose $a, b\in X,$ and $f$ is a local homeomorphism.

1. The pullback (in fact, any limit or colimit would work here) $\downarrow a\times_X\downarrow b$ as an open sublocale of $X.$ Do we have $$f\left(\downarrow a\underset{X}{\times}\downarrow b\right)\simeq \downarrow f(a)\underset{\downarrow f(X)}{\times}\downarrow f(a)\, ?$$
2. Since monomorphisms are preserved by any right adjoint functor, is the inclusion $\downarrow f(a)\to \downarrow f(X)$ a monomorphism?

I think "Yes" to all these questions. But something seems wrong, and therefore thought to seek opinions from experts.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Adjoints in what 2-category? Yes, every frame homomorphism, considered as a monotone map, has a right adjoint in the 2-category of posets; and frame homomorphisms that correspond to open maps of locales also have left adjoints, again considered as monotone maps. But having both adjoints doesn’t mean they are equal. This does happen if you have a frame isomorphism (i.e. locale homeomorphism).

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thanks. I am thinking in the category of locales. Are the formal duals of $f_!$ and $f_*$ are maps of locales?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Proposition 1.7.5 of Handbook of Categorical Algebra( Volume 3) by Francis Borceux says something like $f_!=f_∗$ for local homeomorphisms, though it is not completely clear to me.

Comment: 1.7.5 doesn't say anything about $f_*$ at all. Try calculating some examples! For instance, any morphism between discrete locales is a local homeomorphism.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Seems like I have been confused by these notions. Help me to unravel these. Here is how I currently understood these notions. Since $f^*$ (inverse image) preserve all suprema it has a right adjoint $f_*$ called "direct image".  In case $f^*$ preserve all meets it also has a left adjoint $f_!.$ When this new map $f_!$ satisfy Frobenius reciprocity, $f^*$ is a Heyting algebra homomorphism and $f$ preserve open sublocales. Am I correct? I know this is bit far from what I asked in the question, but seems like I seriously misunderstood something.

Comment: In _topos theory_, as a matter of tradition, the right adjoint of the inverse image functor is called the direct image functor, but this is an unfortunate misnomer. There appears to be no such tradition in locale theory. The direct image is supposed to be the _left_ adjoint of the inverse image, and this is the way Borceux uses terminology.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Ohh... I see. Thank you for taking your time to clarify this to me. If I correctly understood your previous comments, both $f_!, f_*$ need not to be frame isomorphisms. Therefore a local homeomorphism $f$ may have no adjoints in the category of Locales. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed, local homeomorphisms need not have adjoints in the 2-category of locales. Notice that $f_!$ is not guaranteed to preserve $\top$, for example.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thank you so much for your time. I will write an answer to my own question following your suggestions. Out of curiosity, since $f$ doesn't preserve pullbacks (or any limit or colimit), is there any relation between $f\left(\downarrow a\underset{X}{\times}\downarrow b\right)$ and $\downarrow f(a)\underset{\downarrow f(X)}{\times}\downarrow f(a)$ in general? Does one less than or equal to the other?

Comment: Since you have a local homeomorphism you may as well work with $f_!$ instead. It is a fact that for any monotone map $m$, $m (a \wedge b) \le m (a) \wedge m (b)$ (when the relevant meets exist).